# How to use update() method of ManagerInterface in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

How to change/update specific cell in column `"name"` in table `"auth_item"`?

I supposed, that I need to use `update()` method of ManagerInterface, but I didn't find any examples of how to do it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Create model -> using findOne($id) gets model details and use save() function for update records,

Answer (score 0):

Create `Authitem` model and use below function

```
        $model = Authitem::findOne($id);
        $model->name = 'Abc';
        $model->save(false);
```

`false` to ignore validation.

Hope this help to you.